# VS 2017 Ошибка при создании нового проекта

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переустанавливать vs, запускать от имени админа, использовать только латиницу в пути к проекту. И постоянно выбивает такую ошибку